# Property 'bind' does not exist on type '() => any'

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have been using both Javascript and Typescript for quite some time and this one should be really easy. But I never had the need to `bind` using Typescript, and this is just baffling me.

This is an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

var unboundGetX = module.getX;
console.log(unboundGetX()); // The function gets invoked at the global scope
// expected output: undefined

var boundGetX = unboundGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX());
// expected output: 42
```

Typescript says `Property 'bind' does not exist on type '() => string'.ts(2339)`

Well I know it does exist, it's just a function.

Also why are a function and arrow function typed the same?

```
const f1 = function() {}; // const f1: () => void
const f2 = () => {};      // const f2: () => void
```

Edit:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "es2015",
        "baseUrl": "./"
    }
}
```

Comment: This compiles in the playground. But your first call to get will raise an error that `this` is undefined:https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/G4QwTgBAtg9gJgVwDYFMIF4IG8BQEIAeAXBACwBMANHhAOYoAuAGiQGYIB2AxgwJYwcAFAEpsNfGEYIwHCAwAWvAM4A6AgG4aAXxw6coSJwBGMTnADijJhmjxkKFfWab94CCbOXmN46Y4WrFSNef0FYRFRhTS4BJRhUFSQYWkEPfy8mESicAHociBQCAAcUHhQ4CFMGIoQGEgocHBiOOISklN9PKyz1CDyIAFEwMBhIJRCuNAVlCBmzFFYQ8qA

Comment: Thanks, but I even installed the same TS version and there is still that error. Even if I `const fun: Function = null;
fun.bind();` it says `Property 'bind' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

Comment: What tsconfig.json do you have ? maybe you removed the default libs ?

Comment: Edited with tsconfig.

Comment: Still works, not sure what the problem is with your installation of TS (maybe try reinstalling it ?)

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
var module = {
    x: 42,
    getX: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

var boundGetX = module.getX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX());
// output: 42
```